# Changing input type for linear learner to csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run linear learner on a simple dataset.  My csv of data is uploaded to a bucket.  The problem is that when I run it I get the following error:

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job linear-learner-2020-05-23-22-31-40-894: Failed. Reason: ClientError: Unable to read data channel 'train'. Requested content-type is 'application/x-recordio-protobuf'. Please verify the data matches the requested content-type. (caused by MXNetError)

Caused by: [22:34:37] /opt/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/AIAlgorithmsCppLibs/AIAlgorithmsCppLibs-2.0.2746.0/AL2012/generic-flavor/src/src/aialgs/io/iterator_base.cpp:100: (Input Error) The header of the MXNet RecordIO record at position 0 in the dataset does not start with a valid magic number.
```

I did some googling and it says to change the content_type to 'text/csv'.  My question is, how do I do this?  Or does anyone know how to get this working?  Thanks!  Here is my linear learner code:

```
container = get_image_uri(boto3.Session().region_name, 'linear-learner')

linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                      role,
                                      train_instance_count = 1,
                                      train_instance_type = 'ml.c4.xlarge',
                                      output_path = output_location,
                                      sagemaker_session = sess)

linear.set_hyperparameters(predictor_type = 'regressor',
                          mini_batch_size = 200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SageMaker input channels:

```
train_data = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(
    "s3://my-bucket/path/to/train",
    distribution="FullyReplicated",
    content_type="text/csv",
    s3_data_type="S3Prefix",
    record_wrapping=None,
    compression=None
)

validation_data = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(
    "s3://my-bucket/path/to/validation",
    distribution="FullyReplicated",
    content_type="text/csv",
    s3_data_type="S3Prefix",
    record_wrapping=None,
    compression=None
)

linear.fit({"train": train_data, "validation": validation_data})
```

[See this example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/linear_learner_abalone/Linear_Learner_Regression_csv_format.ipynb)